# Android app crashes on startup if I'm signed into a test account under alpha testing?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I've created an Android game using the Unity game engine. I utilize leaderboards/achievements and in-app purchases for my app.

To test the IAPs, I had to submit and publish my app to alpha in the Google Play Developer Console. It then asks me to setup close or open alpha testing. I chose close testing and entered my test account details.

In addition to that, I've also set up the same test account under `Settings>Account Details>License Testing` and `GameServices>Testing Access` in the Developer Console as well.

Now when I deploy my app to my device, the app crashes on startup everytime. This happens if I'm signed in to my test account on the device. I get a notification saying "Unfortunately (app name) has stopped" after it launches.

Now the weird thing is that if I'm signed in on another Google account on my device, the app DOES NOT crash on startup.

This only started to happen when I added my test account as part of the close alpha testing group.

I have now removed my test account from the close alpha group and I'm currently waiting for the changes to be approved by Google Play and see if my test account would still cause my app to crash.

I don't have the slightest clue on why this is happening. I have published 2 Android apps before and didn't have this problem. But that was before Google implemented the close or open alpha testing feature. I didn't have to deal with that feature back then.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Its not weird that your app code crashes due to an issue with those parts of the code that handle a google service such as IAP. Different accounts could trigger different events in the code where you obviously have a problem...

of which you can find that problem via logcat. Trigger the problem and it will show up in logcat.

Comment: A stack trace of the crash will let us help you much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I think I found the culprit already. When I removed my test account from the closed alpha test group, my app doesn't crash anymore on startup. This leads me to think that there's something wrong with alpha test accounts and their communication with Google Play Services (Play Games and Billing for me) because my app tries to sign in to Google Play (for leaderboard access) and requests the IAPs on startup.

Hope this helps other devs who might face this issue.